# Why does this happen when I run the code?

Tags: javascript, function, browser, console.log

When I run this, my computer start lagging and browser shows(not responding)

```js
let number8 = 0.1;
while (number8 <= 11.5) {
   console.log(number8);
   number = number8 + 2;
}
```

Comment: You never change the value of  `number8`, so the loop will never stop.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if this will solve the issue but your `while` loop never finishes, that may be causing the lag.

Maybe you misspelled the `number8` variable and put just `number` in the line 4:

```js
number = number8 + 2;
```

This one should work

```js
let number8 = 0.1;
while (number8 <= 11.5) {
   console.log(number8);
   number8 = number8 + 2;
}
```

Now the `while` loop will end when `number8 <= 11.5`

Comment: That won’t finish either since `number8 + 2` is also constant

Comment: Than that's pop up- ReferenceError: number is not defined

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen that's true, my mistake!

Comment: @ImantsBrokāns I rewrited the code, let me know if the output was what you're expecting.